# How to get pianobar working with tor and polipo

Tags: proxy, tor, pandora, pianobar

Wanting to listen to [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com) from outside the US, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) and changed my `/etc/tor/torrc` file according to the instructions [here](http://openpandora.blogspot.com/2007/06/complete-guide-for-using-openpandora.html).

I learned about [pianobar](https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar), a console-based Pandora player, and decided to give it a try. However, I kept getting the same error:

```
(i) Login... Network error: Connection refused.
```

In `~/.config/pianobar/config` I tried each of the following lines, to no avail:

```
proxy = http://localhost:8118/
control_proxy = http://localhost:8118/
control_proxy = http://localhost:9050/
```

Same error every time.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the solution was simple - just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

So the config file now looks like:

```
control_proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8118/
user = <my username>
password = <my password>
```

From looking at `strace` output, it seems that the problem has something to do with IPv6, but I haven't investigated further.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you use HTTP not a SOCKS proxy