# Configuring Pianobar proxy

Tags: proxy, pandora, pianobar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get pianobar working with tor and polipo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14259/how-to-get-pianobar-working-with-tor-and-polipo)

I've made a proxy as listed [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/) is there any way to make pianobar use that so i can connect to pandora? I'm outside the US.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14259/how-to-get-pianobar-working-with-tor-and-polipo)